# How can I make my flutter_sound recorded file readable by my Flask API?

Tags: python, flutter, flask, audio

So I am trying to build a web application in flutter that records audio and then sends it to a Flask server for additional processing and a machine learning prediction, before returning the percentage to flutter in order to be displayed. The file POSTs to Flask perfectly, and I can save it to my computer and play it. I can change it to any format I want, including m4a, wav, etc. However, when I attempt to process the data (and load it through librosa, pydub, soundfile, or anything else), none of these libraries seem to recognize the input. When I try other audio files of various format, I have no trouble reading and opening them.

Something appears to be fundamentally different about the flutter_sound files, though they ostensibly have normal properties. I would greatly appreciate any guidance and support on this matter.

Here is the code for recording:
await recorder.startRecorder(
codec: Codec.defaultCodec, toFile: 'flutter_recs');

Here is the code used to export:
if (file != null) {
print('Selected file: ${file.path}');

```
final request = http.MultipartRequest(
  'POST',
  Uri.parse({path to localhost of Flask}),
);

final fileBytes = await file.readAsBytes();
request.files.add(
    http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('audio', fileBytes, filename: file.name));

print('Sending audio file...');
final response = await request.send();
```

I tried changing the way that I processed the audio, from breaking it down into Bytes and rewriting it to a new file, to librosa, audioread, soundfile, and an attempt on ffmpeg. However, the issue seems to lie with the audio files themselves and not the method, as other files work well. I also tried changing the codec while recording, but the recording did not even work unless the codec was set to defaultCodec.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time!